# Can I use a 3rd party video content portal like youtube to upload and post videos on my own web portal?

Tags: django, youtube, video-streaming

I manage a website where users post entertainment content (photos, text). It's developed in Django with postgresql. I am trying to add a video feature on the website - such that everyone can upload their favorite videos on the website and share them.

Instead of building out video streaming infrastructure myself, can I use an existing video service as a viable backend? For instance, using Youtube's API to send all uploaded videos to its servers, and then embed a youtube player in my website that users can utilize to view uploaded videos? Youtube actually [imposes a quota](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#calculating-quota-usage), that computes to about 400 video uploads, 1500 write operations, and 50,000 read operations. My website's scale is already beyond this. Are there any other services I can use? Sorry if this is a newbie question, I actually don't have any experience in this domain. If you point me in the right direction, perhaps giving an illustrative example, I can start getting deeper into this.

Comment: Hey guys... any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I have gotten is getting a bizspark plus subscription that is free for one and a half years. After that one can use Azure media services to get the job done.